# Codeigniter issues when loading Model

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter and I am having some issues loading a model in my constructor method. Could someone help me out? Below is the code from the controller I am trying to load the model from...

```
 <?php

    class Login extends CI_Controller {

        function Login(){
            $this->load->model('membership_model');
        }

        public function index(){
            $this->load->view('login_view.php');
        }

        public function authenticate(){
            $user = $this->input->post('username');
            $pass = sha1($this->input->post('password'));
            if($user != null && $pass != null){
                $access = $this->membership_model->request_access($user, $pass);
                if($access == true){
                    $cookie = array(
                        'name'   => 'username',
                        'value'  => $user,
                        'expire' => '86500',
                        'domain' => 'unleashourmedia.com',
                        'path'   => '/',
                        'prefix' => '',
                        'secure' => TRUE
                    );

                    $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
                    echo "cookie";
                } else {
                    redirect('login');
                }
            }
        }

    }

?>
```

Comment: What's the issue? Any error messages?

Comment: can u display what is the error message you are getting???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are not calling the constructor of the parent class.

Add this as the first line in your constructor:

```
parent::__construct();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   function Login(){
  $this->load->model("membership_model","",TRUE); 
  }
```

Comment: This just makes the model auto-connect to the database, I don't see the point of doing this here (though I must say the question isn't clear at all on what the problem _is_ )

Comment: Here is the error message: Fatal error: Call to a member function model() on a non-object in /homepages/21/d255080677/htdocs/du/ci/application/controllers/login.php on line 6

Answer (score 0):

```
    //make sure you call parent constructor before anything in that constructor like this
    function Login(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('membership_model');
    }

    //and you may also try to name the constructor __construct
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('membership_model');
    }
```